# Merge associations with the same keys, same in a sense by user's definition

Tags: string-manipulation, associations

I know that it is the standard functionality of `Merge` to combine the values of the same keys among associations.

Now I would like to deal with a situation in which, in my associations, the keys are strings (English words). And I want to define the sameness as two words having the same result from `WordStem` so that "effects" and "effect" are the same key.

So is it possible for `Merge` to accept such a same test function for the keys, e.g., `Equal@@WordStem[{##}]&`, to determine what keys should be considered the same and be merged?

---

A MWE goes as below:

```
mergeFunc = x \[Function] {Total[#], Union[Flatten@#2]} & @@ (x\[Transpose]);

Merge[{<|"effect" -> {5, {2, 3}}|>, <|"effects" -> {4, {1, 3, 5}}|>}, mergeFunc]

Merge[{<|"effect" -> {5, {2, 3}}|>, <|"effect" -> {4, {1, 3, 5}}|>}, mergeFunc]
```

> ```
> <|"effect" -> {5, {2, 3}}, "effects" -> {4, {1, 3, 5}}|>
>
> <|"effect" -> {9, {1, 2, 3, 5}}|>
> ```

The second result is desired.

---

**Additional requirement**: no new keys should be introduced.

For example, what if I now have "apple" and "apples" as the keys instead of "effect" and "effects"?

That means I need the word stems as the criterion but not as the keys in the merged result.

Comment: Can you give example associations?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less Please see the update.

Answer (score 5):

```
 data = {<|"effect" -> {5, {2, 3}}|>, <|"effects" -> {4, {1, 3, 5}}|>};
 Merge[KeyMap[WordStem]/@ data, mergeFunc]
```

> <|"effect" -> {9, {1, 2, 3, 5}}|>

Also

```
 GroupBy[ data, First @* WordStem @* Keys -> First, mergeFunc]
```

> <|"effect" -> {9, {1, 2, 3, 5}}|>

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
data = <|"effect" -> {5, {2, 3}}, "effects" -> {4, {1, 3, 5}}|>;
Merge[
 KeyValueMap[{key, value} \[Function] WordStem[key] -> value, data],
 mergeFunc
 ]
```

> <|"effect" -> {9, {1, 2, 3, 5}}|>